# Как получить сообщения из чата в Slack

Tags: java, slack

Необходимо получить сообщения из определенного чата
Делаю запрос:

```
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("token", authToken);
        params.put("channel", 
        String result = session.postGenericSlackCommand(params, "channels.history");
```

А в ответ получаю:

```
{
   "ok":false,
   "error":"missing_scope",
   "needed":"channels:history",
   "provided":"identify,bot:basic",
   "warning":"superfluous_charset",
   "response_metadata":{
      "warnings":[
         "superfluous_charset"
      ]
   }
}
```

Через сайт слака с тестированием данной апихи, на выходе идет ошибка

```
{
   ok: false,
   error: "missing_scope",
   needed: "channels:history",
   provided: "identify,bot:basic"
}
```

https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history/test

Хотя другой функционал из апихи с этим же токеном и айдишника чата всё работает

Comment: Вот описание ошибки из документации:  

The token used is not granted the specific scope permissions required to complete this request.

Comment: Доступы предоставили, но теперь просто не могу подключить бота к слаку (приложение реинсталлил)
На выходе коннекта ошибка: not_allowed_token_type